# how to reset padding on all pages

Tags: css, ionic-framework, triangulation

I have a IONIC 5 angular 10 project.
I am not sure what I changed but now all my pages are shifted to the right and to bottom, some padding has been set to all pages. as in the picture the red area is the shifted area

Which variable or css element I need to change to set it to normal

[image]

Comment: I am not ionic developer, but I can see its padded from the left top side, you can check those side and reduce it

Comment: This is the point, I checked and there is many many css variables and css elements and i am not sure which one is doing that.

Comment: Which element has the padding (or margin)?